# Was Jesus tempted during the forty days in Luke 4?

Tags: luke

Luke 4:1-2 NASB

> [1]Jesus, full of the Holy Spirit, returned from the Jordan and was led around by the Spirit in the wilderness
>   ***[2]for forty days, being tempted*** by the devil. And He ate nothing during those days, and ***when they had ended***, He became hungry.

In the light of the ambiguous statements in the above text,its not clear whether Jesus underwent any temptation during the forty days.

No temptation is actual mentioned but only after the end of that period

So in the above text it would seems Jesus spend forty days fasting & was only tempted after the end of forty days.

How can we understand the above text?

Comment: *No temptation is actually mentioned* - Other than the obvious desire to eat and drink and leave the desert for a more comfortable place ?

Comment: *'Jesus was in the led in the wilderness for forty days, being tempted'* — what's ambiguous about that? The lack of a detailed description of the forty days doesn't make the statement that he was 'being tempted' ambiguous.

Comment: @MarkEdward,what is ambiguous is that the forty days were spent in fasting rather  temptation.The statement seems to be alluding to  the temptation having taken place within the framework of the forty days

Comment: The translation you provided isn't ambiguous. It says 'and he ate nothing'. The temptation and the fasting are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: There are *heavy* parallels between the 'temptations' of the Israelites in the Exodus, and Christ in the desert. Laid out well in [this video.](https://youtu.be/bJez9w5EsVU?t=625). Where they failed, He remained faithful. Tempations here therefore means 'tryings'. He was 'tried' by the devil. This is most clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is clearly an hermeneutic question, and it beggars belief that anyone would want to shut it down.

Here is the Greek of the passage ...

[image]

... which says:

> <sup>1</sup>Then, full of the Holy Spirit, Jesus returned from the Jordan, having been led by the spirit in the wilderness <sup>2</sup>forty days, and being tested by the Devil. He ate nothing during that time, and at the end of it he was hungry.

Jesus ate absolutely nothing <sup>1</sup> *ἐν ταῖς ἡμέραις ἐκείναις* - "in the days the same" or "during that time".

During what time? During the time just mentioned, the forty days, when he was being led about by the Holy Spirit and being tested by the Devil.

---

**Notes:**

1. emphatic double-negative: *οὐκ ἔφαγεν οὐδὲν* - "not ate he nothing".

Answer (score -1):

The word commonly translated "tempted" also has in its semantic domain the usage "tested". I see the devil as being very similar to Javert, the overly ambitious policeman in the wonderful classic "Les Miserable" (and similar to the vicious police force of the USA), in the employ of the crown but absurdly and brutally bent on producing arrests and convictions. In his role as "District Attorney" he not only hopes to expose him as not being a son of God (a heavenly being), nor *the* son of God (messiah) but seeks to trick him up and to forfeit his rights, as Adam was undermined by the serpent. But all this ill will and jealousy is under the control of God who by his spirit/breath subjects him to the interrogation.

Now since one of the tests involves his submission to the will of God in regards to not eating ("command these stones to become bread"), the pangs of starvation serve to make the test for eating all but unbearable. Consider Esau selling his birthright.

So the fasting was part of his testing even though there is no indication that he was tempted at that time, only at the end of the 40 days when he began starving.

Comment: I edited your answer to reflect "devil" consistent with the NASB. Not saying they aren't one in the same; just trying to bring consistency to this answer.